# Puppet Invalid parameter string on Firewall

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-14.04, puppetmaster

Using the Firewall module version 1.9 in puppet 3.8.7, I am getting the following error:

> Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter string on Firewall

Here is my Puppet Firewall rule.

```
firewall {
"051 asterisk-set-rate-limit-register":
  string => "REGISTER sip:",
  string_algo => "bm",
  dport     => '5060',
  proto     => 'udp',
  recent    => 'set',
  rname     => 'VOIPREGISTER',
  rsource   => 'true';
"052 asterisk-drop-rate-limit-register":
  string => "REGISTER sip:",
  string_algo => "bm",
  dport     => '5060',
  proto     => 'udp',
  action    => 'drop',
  recent    => 'update',
  rseconds  => '600',
  rhitcount => '5',
  rname     => 'VOIPREGISTER',
  rsource   => true,
  rttl      => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that the firewall class was not instantiated.
I also added a firewall purge command so that only the below rules are present. That is handy so that holes are not accidentally left in the firewall.

Here is the code that works on my system:

```
class { 'firewall': }

resources { 'firewall':
    purge => true,
}

firewall { "051 asterisk-set-rate-limit-register":
    string      => "REGISTER sip:",
    string_algo => "bm",
    dport       => '5060',
    proto       => 'udp',
    recent      => 'set',
    rname       => 'VOIPREGISTER',
    rsource     => 'true';
}
firewall { "052 asterisk-drop-rate-limit-register":
    string      => "REGISTER sip:",
    string_algo => "bm",
    dport       => '5060',
    proto       => 'udp',
    action      => 'drop',
    recent      => 'update',
    rseconds    => '600',
    rhitcount   => '5',
    rname       => 'VOIPREGISTER',
    rsource     => true,
    rttl        => true;
}
```

---

## notes

I tested that on my puppet installation with the `puppetlabs-firewall` module installed.

Successfully applied.

Comment: Is this required? I normally chain other rules with a semi colon separator under the same class selector.

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: crud, can you post your full firewall excerpt? I will update mine based upon yours.

Comment: My Firewall string manifest is identical to yours above plus separate firewall rules for port 5060, etc.

Comment: I will do an in-depth rebuild and test when I get back to my place. I just happen to need to have a firewall component on my system to.

Comment: hi, did you ever get this tested?

Comment: Try again. I just rewrote until it worked. I have tested this time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering about the class firewall since I had other firewall rules working without this. I can't purge my firewall as other manifests will also set firewall rules for this server. I'll try on Monday.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I see from the documentation it says this - string: Set the pattern for string matching. Requires the string_matching feature. How would I implement that?

Comment: Did you only run the above code? By itself, like (sudo) `puppet apply \etc\puppetlabs\code\environments\production\manifests\test.pp` where `test.pp` is the above answer only?

Comment: Also, is it possible for you to update to the latest puppet version? E.g. puppet v5.x?

Comment: I can't update to the latest puppet version, only modules working with 3.8. I did run an exact copy of the above code. The class was already defined in a global puppet firewall manifest and rejected as a duplicate.

Comment: Please do not run this code with any other code. Run it as standalone. We need to find where the code is having trouble.

Comment: Ok. The puppet system I am using runs a dozen or more servers so I will need to set this up on a VM for one instance.

Comment: When I mean run the code by itself, only execute the code that I posted, it does not matter how many servers execute it as long as ONLY the above code runs. It is most likely a good idea to create a VM and put only the above code in a `pp` file and execute only that one `pp` file with the puppet system.

Comment: Using a very basic install of of puppet 4 root@mark-Inspiron-13-7359:~# /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --test
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not find declared class firewall at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:7:1 on node mark-inspiron-13-7359
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Comment: /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module list
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
└── puppetlabs-firewall (v1.9.0)

Comment: Can you try puppet 5?